# Google OAuth 2.0 Access Token Request Error

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I have a small Google App Engine project on GitHub what I "finished" several months ago.

It worked until now (Last use was 2-3 months ago), but it seems the Google changed something and I don't find what the real problem is and how I can solve it.

The problem is in this file (line 59):
[File](https://github.com/apostx/language_mentor/blob/master/src/main/java/languagementor/db/api/google/TokenManager.java)

Code:

```
public class TokenManager {

static private final String TOKEN_URL = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token";
static private final String ENC = "UTF-8";

private String _refreshToken;
private String _clientId;
private String _clientSecret;

private final Gson _gson = new Gson();
private TokenData _tokenData = new TokenData();

...

private void refreshAccessToken() throws Exception {
    String payload = "client_secret=$client_secret&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=$refresh_token&client_id=$client_id";
    payload = payload.replace("$client_secret", URLEncoder.encode(_clientSecret, ENC));
    payload = payload.replace("$refresh_token", URLEncoder.encode(_refreshToken, ENC));
    payload = payload.replace("$client_id", URLEncoder.encode(_clientId, ENC));

    HTTPRequest request = new HTTPRequest(new URL(TOKEN_URL), HTTPMethod.POST);
    request.setPayload(payload.getBytes(ENC));

    String stringData = new String(URLFetchServiceFactory.getURLFetchService().fetch(request).getContent(), ENC);

    _tokenData = _gson.fromJson(stringData, TokenData.class);
}
```

}

The problem is around the access token request. (I use offline refresh token.)

The response is this:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad Request",
    "error_uri": ""
}
```

1. I have tried to modify the TOKEN_URL to "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token"
2. I have tried to generate new refresh token.
3. I have tried create new OAuth Client ID.

All attempts had same problem.

Have anyone any idea what is wrong?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Ready. Sorry, It seemed to me the post more transparent without code snippet, but I fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

> Probably my previous refresh token was expired. I tried to generating
>   a new but I misunderstood the process and I considered "code"
>   parameter as refresh token.

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline